# Remove space and dash in string python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a string and want to remove all space and dash and underline... I want to output is a string A to Z and 0 to 9.
my version is Python3
for example :

input:

```
fafaf fadfa fafa fa-fa faf_afa@gs!
```

output:

```
fafaffadfafafafafafafafags
```

What should I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

input_ = 'fafaf fadfa fafa fa-fa faf_afa@gs!' 
input_ = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '', input_)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.isalnum()`

```
''.join(e for e in a if e.isalnum())
```

Answer (score 2):

@Rohit has a good answer if if you want it faster do a list comprehension:

```
print(''.join([i for i in s if i.isalnum()]))
```

**Demo:**

```
s='fafaf fadfa fafa fa-fa faf_afa@gs!'
print(''.join([i for i in s if i.isalnum()]))
```

Output:

```
fafaffadfafafafafafafafags
```

Comment: Yup @U9-Forward

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re

letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "", your_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want another option:

```
s='fafaf fadfa fafa fa-fa faf_afa@gs!'
s.translate(str.maketrans('', '','_-@ !'))
```

Output:

```
'fafaffadfafafafafafafafags'
```

The third argument of str.maketrans(), it must be a string, whose characters will be mapped to None in the result. That means they will be deleted.

And the documents: [str.maketrans()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) and [str.translate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.translate)